# "before" method returns unexpected newline character in Pexpect

Tags: python, telnet, pexpect

Short scenario: I send telnet commands using Python and Pexpect library.

I encountered a "child.before" behavior that I can't change or understand. When I read the output of `myResult=child.before` I see the command that I sent(using `child.sendline()`), the result of the command and eventually the prompt.

Often,however,the **command sent is not on a single line**. If the command is long enough a newline character is introduced.

Example:

Code:

```
child.sendline('tail -f /myLocation | grep "something"')
child.expect('myPrompt',timeout=100)
myResult=child.before
print(myResult)
```

Result:

- tail -f /myLocation | grep
- "something"
- Command output

Expected Result

- tail -f /myLocation | grep "something"
- Command output

Because of this I cannot safety use `myResult.split('\n')` method.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: You could try using `send()` instead of `sendline()`.  (You need to put an extra `\n` at the end.)

Comment: I tried and nothing has changed. After several tests I observed that for commands larger than 55 characters it introduces a newline character. This does not hold true for the output of the command which can be longer.

Comment: My two cents: 1) I wonder if the issue is related to the width of the terminal window; try to increase it to see if the issue still exists. 2) As a workaround, before sending you own command, issue a `sendline('stty -echo')` to disable echo of command; and use `sendline('stty echo')` to get it back when necessary. In this way, you just need to deal with `stty -echo` from `child.before`.

Comment: The second workaround worked for me. Thank very much for your time!

Comment: `child.setecho(False)` is a more direct way to disable echo, that doesn't depend on what process you're running.